# How to get MSI version?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use this code from the tutorial *[Getting version from MSI without installing it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31021/Getting-version-from-MSI-without-installing-it)*, but when I try to add the "msi.dll" to Visual Studio 2010 as a reference I get this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'msi.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> This file may not be a managed assembly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use "Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" from the Wix project's Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  DTF provides a managed wrapper for much of msi.dll.  Wix also provides helpful documentation.

Using DTF here is how I accessed the version number of an msi in C#

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace Msi.Tables
{
    public class PropertyTable
    {
        public static string Get(string msi, string name)
        {
            using (Database db = new Database(msi))
            {
                return db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property` = '{0}'", name) as string;
            }
        }
        public static void Set(string msi, string name, string value)
        {
            using (Database db = new Database(msi, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
            {
                db.Execute("UPDATE `Property` SET `Value` = '{0}' WHERE `Property` = '{1}'", value, name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then from my application

```
string msiVersion = PropertyTable.Get("MyInstall.msi", "ProductVersion");
```

You can use Orca to view the msi tables.  MSDN provides documentation on the [Property Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The details on [SQL syntax for Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also available in MSDN

Comment: The msi.dll assembly is installed by default in Windows XP and Windows 7 machine ? If not installed, what I need for installed it ?

Comment: This DLL is not included in Windows and is not part of Windows Installer.  It's part of Windows Installer XML which can be found @ www.wixtoolset.org.  You can deploy it privately with your application.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Thanks for the correction!  Deleted my erroneous comment :)

Comment: To find this package on NuGet search for 'DTF'

Answer (score 3):

[image]

to register asembly on 32 bit machine

```
REGSVR32 MSI.DLL
```

to register asembly on 64 bit machine

```
cd \windows\syswow64 regsvr32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\msi.dll
```

Comment: +1, the thing that tips you off to it being COM is the `Activator.CreateInstance` code in the tutorial.

Comment: Ya I also tried that as well. I have .net 4.0 console app and when I try to add that I get "Could not add a reference to {00C1902-00000-000-C000-0000000004...} Libary not registered (Exception from HRESULT:0x8002801D (Type_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))

Comment: Tested same code in the tutorial with .net 4.0 console app and it is working without any issues.

Comment: Hmm made a new console and still does not work. Any idea on how to register it?

Comment: If you're on a 64bit machine, you may want to add `/platform:x86` if it is only a 32bit COM library.

Comment: @UnhandledException - I am on 64 bit machine and I get The module "C:\Windows\system32\msi.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80040201.

For more information about this problem, searchonline using the error code as a search term.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - where do you add that?

Comment: @UnhandledException - Never did not know you needed to run this under an admin cmd prompt. Says it is registered but still get the same error when I try to add it as a reference in VS2010

Comment: Under project properties, Build, Platform.

Answer (score 1):

From codeproject:

> To access the version number or other product related stuff, we need to have the DLL reference in Visual Studio .NET.
>   DLL name: msi.dll (which exists in system32).

I think you should add reference to your project in Solution Explorer (right click on References in SE -> Add Reference -> then browse to msi.dll in system32 directory).

Comment: Sorry.Let me re-edit the question. The error I got is because of me trying to add msi.dll as a reference.

Comment: Not sure. I did not give you it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `system.management` to references and include the namespace.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product where Name LIKE '%Your MSI Name%'");

foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
  var version = obj["Version"];                
}
```

This will give you version of any software installed in control panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var path = @"C:\Users\self\path\to\your\installFile.msi";
    var view = ((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer")))
        .OpenDatabase(path, 0)
        .OpenView("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'");
    view.Execute();
    string version = view.Fetch().StringData(1);
    Console.WriteLine(version);
```

No references, no NuGets, no nothin'