# How to set MSI custom property

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Ultimately I'm wanting to determine the version of an MSI without installing. There are answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233400/how-to-get-msi-version) but in my case I am actually generating the MSI (using WIX) and figured I should be able to set a custom property, viewable via right-mouse->properties->custom on the msi file, that represents the version number. [image]  It would have no purpose other than to enable someone to query an msi file to see the version before installing (the .msi file will have the version number imbeded in it's filename but a custom property seems a better idea).  Thanks

I should add I have tried "`<Property Id='Version' Value="27.3" />`" in WIX wxs file under `<Wix><Product>` to no avail. It does not appear anywhere viewable via properties on the generated msi file from Explorer

Details from File explorer->right-mouse->properties
[image]

Comment: Don't you have the version number in the details tab?

Comment: yes, but only via overloading another field (Subject) - see second screen-shot. One would think Version should be shown on the Details tab but not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSI's version isn't in the summary info stream, it's in the property table and you get it via that link. You have no choice but to overload one of the standard fields, such as Author.

Comment: thanks ... and no way to set a custom property (as per first screen-shot in question)? Will accept this answer if that's confirmed.

Comment: The Manufacturer in the Package element ends up as author in the details, if that works for you. The custom stream isn't AFAIK anything specific to an MSI file, it's just another internal data stream in the file, this kind of thing http://support.microsoft.com/KB/105763  That stream *might* be called Custom. Also this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2670/Accessing-alternative-data-streams-of-files-on-an